# flash actionscript loadMovie

Tags: flash, actionscript

It works if I use

`loadMovie("http://graph.facebook.com/100000108805716/picture", "imageLoader2");`

but as I try to pass that link as variable from server this way:

`loadVariables("http://paulius.shnaresys.com/suktukas/kodas.php", this, "GET");
loadMovie(draugas_1, "imageLoader");`

It doesn't work. I know that the variable is passed as I can output in to text field. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
loadVariables("http://paulius.shnaresys.com/suktukas/kodas.php", this, "GET");
onEnterFrame = function()
{ 
     if( draugas_1 ) 
     { 
         loadMovie(draugas_1, "imageLoader");  
         delete this.onEnterFrame
     }
}
```

`loadVariables` happens asynchronously, which means that some time passes between the call of `loadVariables` and the return of the values which `loadVariables` retrieves. This means you need to wait until the variable exists before using it in `loadMovie`. The onEnterFrame is more or less the same way that the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001191.html) recommend. They use a setInterval, which technically makes fewer calls, but I personally prefer enterFrame to setInterval in AS2, especially in these circumstances.

The good news? Either way, you shouldn't have to wait too long that the user notices (or cares)

Comment: +1 of remembering how loadVariables works, but you need to clear that `onEnterFrame` once the load in confirmed

Comment: Yea. I realized that. The edit was in before you even commented. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the example for the documentation?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001319.html#390433

```
loadVariables("http://paulius.shnaresys.com/suktukas/kodas.php", this, "GET"); 
function checkVarsLoaded() {
    if(draugas_1 != undefined) {
        clearInterval(param_interval);
        loadMovie(draugas_1, "imageLoader");
    }
}
var param_interval = setInterval(checkVarsLoaded, 100);
```